# How to include php function in javascript(Alertify.js) that had been echo in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using alertify.js library to prompt a cormfirmation to user. Ex if user press ok , it will run certain php funtion. The alert are echo using php. but it return an error.

```
<?php
    include('header.php');

    if( isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete'){
       $id = $_GET['id'];


            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alertify.confirm("Confirm Title", "Confirm Message", function(){ alertify.success("Ok")'.
                    if($user->deleteAccount($id)){
                           $_SESSION['current_url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];



                 /*  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                               window.location.replace('clear_Post.php');
                    </script>";*/
           }
            .' }
                , function(){ alertify.error("Cancel")});
                   </script>';



   }
```

?>

Comment: I believe this is impossible.

Comment: If you need live data from the server during a client-side event thread, then you have to use AJAX.

Comment: is there any better way for the system to make the confirmation either user really want to delete or cancel when click delete button

Comment: Use javascript confirmation. If user says ok then only submit the form to php script and delete.

Comment: ok tq very much...had done it using form onsubmit